# Comparing counts (or percentages) between two groups...stuck

Tags: statistical-significance

I have what on the surface seems like a simple problem but I cannot figure out what is the appropriate test -- I am not a statistician...

I am trying to determine an appropriate metric to stratify patients in regards to getting toxicity (essentially trying to find a constraint so we can avoid it during treatment)

In group A, patients who met constraint A had a toxicity rate of 26% (5/19) vs 86% (12/14) for those who didn't.

In group B, patients who met constraint B had a toxicity rate of 55% (6/11) vs 72% (55/76) for those who didn't.

What test would I need to determine if constraint A was more effective stratifying patients (or reducing the proportion of patients with toxicity) versus constraint B.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This basically looks like a 2x2x2 table ([toxicity, non-toxicity] x [constraint, non-constraint] x [group A, group B]).  [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423722/analysis-2x2x2-contingency-table) is similar.

I'm not *super* familiar with this area (will delete this answer if a better one supersedes it), but you can do:

- a chi-squared test with the expected values for the ([toxic, non-toxic] x [constraint, non-constraint]) combinations set equal to the average across groups
- a binomial regression with `glm(cbind(toxic, non-toxic) ~ constraint*group, family = binomial)`, testing the interaction for significance
- an appropriate version of the [Cochrane-Mantel-Haenszel test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics)? (Based on the Wikipedia page it looks like this doesn't quite do what you wants - it tests the overall [toxicity x constraint] interaction across groups rather than comparing the groups ...)

If you feel like digging in there's probably something in Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* that covers this case ...

Comment: If the question is which constraint reduces the toxicity, then a test for association doesn't seem to be sufficient since it can test for a difference in the probability that toxicity = 1, but not for the direction of the difference?